# A simple question about possible biased estimates in linear regression: do they matter?

Tags: regression, bias, independence

I am using the framework of a regression to compare how an aggregate statistic masks certain features in its disaggregated parts. For example, I want to look at how the height of people working in the banking industry have changed in the past 20 years and show that not separating men from women in this equation leads to estimation bias. (This is a made up example).

What I do to compare this is take all the averages and put them into a pool (the total average, height of men average, and height of women's average). So for each company, I have three average heights. I then plug this into a regression as follows-

Average Height = The type of statistic + year + year*type of statistic + (random intercepts to deal with repeated measures over time and repeated measures within a year).

Now, there are issues with dependence since the average height of men and average height of women is dependent on the total average height.

But will this even matter if all I am trying to do is show how aggregating a statistic can lead to very different estimates from a disaggregated version?

Comment: This sounds a lot like the general issue of [omitted-variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias). What exactly are you trying to accomplish that goes beyond documenting that phenomenon?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Mainly I just want to document the phenomenon and estimates its extent and look if that extent has changed over time.